# how to refresh a reportviewer report on postback

Tags: asp.net, .net, reportviewer, rdlc

I have a simple report in VS2012 asp.net, deriving from an .rdlc file which takes in month and year as parameters, which are extracted from their respective dropdowns.  I've set the dropdowns to autopostback, but my report isn't refreshing to reflect the new parameters. In debug, it doesn't even hit the method that retrieves the data.

I'm new to reporting in .net, so any help would be appreciated.  Is there a special method I need to call to make the report reload using new parameters?

Comment: Does your report have the Refresh button? You can enable that separately if necessary. Does the Refresh button actually refresh the report, or does that not work too?

Answer (score 3):

You Can Use this Code

```
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh()
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me . ie in ReportViewerWebForm.aspx.cs

```
DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender,EventArgs e) 
{
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used this code and worked good, hope to be useful!
xReportViewer1.docViewer.DocumentSource = null;